# Application to monitor thread in webservice and mongodb

Tags: web-services, mongodb, jmx

I am trying to monitor my application from end-to-end. My Application consist of a client (Written in asp .net), a webservice (written in java), a database (mongodb). Webservice and mongodb are hosted on one linux server. I already tried installing no of tools on server to analyze data but no one is perfect till now. I have installed munin (Its not showing data for mongodb), wireshark (On linux environment only tshark work, no GUI). JMX from remote machine (Its not showing data for soap based webservice). I find very few tutorial configuring jmx with soap based webservice and no one is good. Please help me to suggest good monitoring tool in my scenario.